# How to add tamil language in FCK Editor

Tags: php, fckeditor, multilingual, tamil

I'm using FCK Editor in my website admin. I have some of the language support in my editor like (English, German,french, etc.,). Now I need to add the Tamil language support to my FCK Editor. If any of one familiar about this FCK Editor language support functionality. Let me know ASAP.

Note : I'm developing PHP Website with this FCK Editor.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer with the following steps ,

**Step 1 :** Create one "tn.js" file for tamil fonts (take one copy from "en.js" [fckeditor/editor/lang/] and replace with tamil font with the name of "tn.js") and upload it into "fckeditor/editor/lang/" directory.

**Step 2 :** Include the language code and language title in "fcklanguagemanager.js" , "fckeditorcode_gecko.js" and "fckeditorcode_ie.js" files.

These files are coming under ,

(1). *fcklanguagemanager.js* ---> fckeditor/editor/_source/internals/

Search the word "AvailableLanguages :" and add the Tamil language code and title
(tn : 'Tamil') with in the available languages array.

(2). fckeditorcode_gecko.js ---> fckeditor/editor/js/

Search the word "AvailableLanguages :" and add the Tamil language code and title
(tn : 'Tamil') with in the available languages array.

(3). fckeditorcode_ie.js ---> fckeditor/editor/js/

Search the word "AvailableLanguages :" and add the Tamil language code and title
(tn : 'Tamil') with in the available languages array.

**Example :**

```
var FCKLanguageManager=FCK.Language={AvailableLanguages:{af:'Afrikaans',ar:'Arabic',bg:'Bulgarian',bn:'Bengali/Bangla',bs:'Bosnian',ca:'Catalan',cs:'Czech',da:'Danish',de:'German',el:'Greek',en:'English','en-au':'English (Australia)','en-ca':'English (Canadian)','en-uk':'English (United Kingdom)',eo:'Esperanto',es:'Spanish',et:'Estonian',eu:'Basque',fa:'Persian',fi:'Finnish',fo:'Faroese',fr:'French','fr-ca':'French (Canada)',gl:'Galician',gu:'Gujarati',he:'Hebrew',hi:'Hindi',hr:'Croatian',hu:'Hungarian',is:'Icelandic',it:'Italian',ja:'Japanese',km:'Khmer',ko:'Korean',lt:'Lithuanian',lv:'Latvian',mn:'Mongolian',ms:'Malay',nb:'Norwegian Bokmal',nl:'Dutch',no:'Norwegian',pl:'Polish',pt:'Portuguese (Portugal)','pt-br':'Portuguese (Brazil)',ro:'Romanian',ru:'Russian',sk:'Slovak',sl:'Slovenian',sr:'Serbian (Cyrillic)','sr-latn':'Serbian (Latin)',sv:'Swedish',th:'Thai',tn:'Tamil',tr:'Turkish',uk:'Ukrainian',vi:'Vietnamese',zh:'Chinese Traditional','zh-cn':'Chinese Simplified'}
```

**Step 3 :** Set the default language to your editor like ,

If you are using JavaScript in your html webpage page means just embed like the following.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
oFCKeditor.Config["AutoDetectLanguage"] = false ;
oFCKeditor.Config["DefaultLanguage"]    = 'tn' ;
</script>
```

If you are using PHP in your webpage page means just embed like the following ,

```
<?php 
$oFCKeditor->Config['AutoDetectLanguage']   = false ;
$oFCKeditor->Config['DefaultLanguage']  = 'en' ;
?>
```

**Step 4 :** Run your webpage to see it in action.

Answer (score 1):

CKEditor supports language selection (see multi-language support [here](http://ckeditor.com/demo)). Tamil is not officially a supported language, but you may implement your own Tamil support. There are many guides on how to do this, see for example http://theholyjava.wordpress.com/2011/04/04/how-to-customize-ckeditor-with-your-own-plugins-skins-configurations/ (the custom language section)

Comment: I'm using FCK Editor Not the CK Editor.

Comment: Ok, CKEditor is the new name of FCKEditor, since version 3.0. Found the following guide on language selection/implementation: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/language-selection-fckeditor/.
This might be of help for pre-CKEditor-versions.

Comment: It's not working for a tamil fonts.,check it and let me know with your examples